# Purging some tables while keeping down time at minimum using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to purge some tables, there are more than a billion records present in the table. I am planing to do this job in short intervals to minimize the down time.

I have 3 tables: `Transaction_log` which is connected with `transaction_summary` and `transaction_key`, I need to purge these three. I want to know best way to do this task. Keep in mind that while purging these tables will be in active use so I am also considering using NOLOOK hint.

Should I just go with *insert-select* or *delete-insert*? I am looking for the correct approach.

edit: Sorry for not mentioning but I don't want to delete the records I still want to keep them, like move them in another table. I am also considering name swapping the tables but I don't know if it will work with constraints.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE SWITCH` can be quite useful in these scenarios. It's typically associated with partitioning, but it can be used to "move" entire tables as well.

Comment: Okay let me research on that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, the `SWITCH` method will not work with foreign key relationships, if that's what is meant by "connected by".  It would help if the table DDL was included in the question rather than just a description of the tables.

Comment: @DanGuzman: agreed -- I'm specifically thinking of the scenario where data is switched away from a table that may have foreign keys *to*, but not foreign keys *from* another table (i.e. "fact" data). In this case the `SWITCH` will work fine and will not even require the foreign keys to exist on the destination. The other way around, of course, will not work as it could violate integrity.

Comment: Actually `transaction_log` is main table and `transaction_log_key` and `monitoring_log` both have foreign keys from `transaction_log`.

Comment: As long as a table has foreign key constraints pointing towards it, the only way of (re)moving rows is `DELETE`. You can optimize that by deleting in batches rather than everything, but you're not going to get around the basic requirement of allowing SQL Server to check that constraints are not violated. You can optimize moving/removing rows from the tables that have no foreign keys going to them, to speed up the `DELETE` checks, or you can consider (temporarily) removing the constraints if you know your applications will behave themselves, but there are no easy shortcuts in that case.